# Facing issue when changed the Combobox items back color

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have requirement as, change of back color for some of combobox's items.

To achieve this, I have done following stuff:

```
  Private Sub cbo_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboRooms.DrawItem
    Try

        If e.Index = 0 Then
            e.DrawBackground()

            ' Get the item text    
            Dim text As String = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString()
            Dim brush As Brush

            brush = Brushes.Black
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, (DirectCast(sender, Control)).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
        Else

            If (e.Index > 0 AndAlso DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index) IsNot Nothing) Then


                ' Draw the background 
                e.DrawBackground()
                Dim combo As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
                ' Get the item text    
                Dim text As String = combo.Items(e.Index).ToString()
                Dim brush As Brush




                If (DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index), GenericListItem(Of objName)).Value.IsExists) Then
                    brush = Brushes.Yellow
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, (DirectCast(sender, Control)).Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
                Else
                    brush = Brushes.Black
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, (DirectCast(sender, Control)).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)

                End If
                ' Determine the forecolor based on whether or not the item is selected    
                'If (e.Index = combo.SelectedIndex) Then

                '    brush = Brushes.White
                '    'e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds)
                '    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, (DirectCast(sender, Control)).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
                'End If


                ' Draw the text    

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

      End Try
```

Problem:

I able to get back color as Yellow through above stuff. But, when I do select/mouse over any item then, its fore color does not change to white and it remains black as it is . so, unable to read the combobox item clearly due to highlighted color(mouseover/selected item) is blue.

Also, over the items where back color is changed, there is no effect while I do mouse over/select the item, it just appear in yellow back color only and no focus color applied.

Can any one give me solution for above points?

Thank You

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what the issue is, but it sounds like you just need to draw the highlighted text when the item is currently highlighted by the mouse:

```
If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds)
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, _
                        SystemColors.HighlightText)
Else
  If DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString = "ccc" Then
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.Bounds)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, _
                          e.Bounds.Location, Color.Black)
  Else
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, e.Bounds)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, _
                          e.Bounds.Location, Color.White)
  End If
End If
```